# Oracle Analytical Functions in XMLElement

Tags: sql, oracle, analytical

I am trying to generate XML from a oracle table using the analytical functions like sum and count over partition. Using following query:

```
SELECT XMLElement("DEPARTMENT", 
            XMLAttributes((sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY deptid)) AS dept_sum,
                            (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY deptid)) AS dept_count),
                XMLAgg(
                    XMLElement("EMPLOYEE", 
                        XMLConcat(XMLElement("EMP_SALARY", a.emp_salary), 
                                     XMLElement("EMP_ADDRESS", a.emp_address))
                    )
                )
         )
   AS "EMP_XML"
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Expecting following Output

```
EMP_XML
-------------------------------------------
<DEPARTMENT dept_sum=150, dept_count=2>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <EMP_SALARY>100</EMP_SALARY>
        <EMP_ADDRESS>Mumbai</EMP_ADDRESS>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <EMP_SALARY>50</EMP_SALARY>
        <EMP_ADDRESS>Hyderabad</EMP_ADDRESS>
    </EMPLOYEE>
</DEPARTMENT>
```

Got below error over the sum and count functions:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

How do I use analytical functions in XMLElement function ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
SELECT XMLElement("DEPARTMENT", 
            XMLAttributes(sum(emp_salary) AS dept_sum,
                            count(1) AS dept_count),
                XMLAgg(
                    XMLElement("EMPLOYEE", 
                        XMLConcat(XMLElement("EMP_SALARY", emp_salary), 
                                     XMLElement("EMP_ADDRESS", emp_address))
                    )
                )
         )
   AS "EMP_XML"
FROM EMPLOYEES
Group by deptid;
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's address a few other things in your query:

You are using the alias `a` but you never defined it. Since you select only from one table, you don't need a table alias. Just write `emp_salary` instead of `a.emp_salary`. However, if for some reason you insist on using an alias anyway, then you must use it for ALL column names, not just for some of them.

You sum over column `amount` - should that, instead, be `emp_salary`?

In the XMLATTRIBUTES clause, don't you need to also show the department number?

Then, to your question (and the error you get). You are using XMLAGG, which is correct - to get the proper document structure. But that is an **aggregate** function - you need a GROUP BY clause. (Obviously, `group by deptid`).

Then, what goes into XMLATTRIBUTES are **aggregate** functions. In that place you need `sum(emp_salary)` and `count(*)`. You would need analytic functions if you wanted to store the sum(salary) and count(rows) IN EACH ROW in the XML document (just like regular analytic functions!) That's not what you are doing; you should be using aggregate, not analytic, functions in XMLATTRIBUTES.